# Match all instances of a character preceded by '/'

Tags: regex, syntax-highlighting, oniguruma

for example, I might have the string

```
/zombie nimble zombie quick
Plants vs Zombies reference
```

and I want to match every 'e' but only from the phrase "zombie nimble zombie quick", as it is preceded by a forward slash.

I can get the contents of the string preceded by the forward slash fairly easily with `\/.*`. 
I can also match the first instance of 'e' in the correct string with `\/.*?\Ke`

But I want to match every instance of 'e' in the correct string in a way that's friendly for VSCode syntax highlighting, which afaik is the .NET flavour

-Jam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using PCRE, you may try the following regex:

```
^(?!\/).*(*SKIP)(*F)|e
```

- `^(?!\/).*` a line doesn't start with a `/`
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` [skips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) the consumed text so far, which is the entire line
- `|` or
- `e` matches `e`, if the `e` didn't get skipped, means it's inside a line that starts with `/`

See the [test cases](https://regex101.com/r/YDg37v/1/)

---

#### Edit

Thanks for Jan's advice.

If the `/` doen't always start from the beginning of a line, you may try

```
^[^\/]*(*SKIP)(*F)|e
```

See the [test cases](https://regex101.com/r/zctjg8/1/)

Comment: Maybe the `/` does not start right at the beginning (use a neg. lookahead then) but +1 for `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`. See [**this demo**](https://regex101.com/r/6OzxcS/1/) for a slash not starting right at the beginning of the line. Using other delimiters (e.g. `~`) you could as well use `^(?!/)...`, see https://regex101.com/r/gseRUF/1

Comment: i want to accept both answers because they're both good but this one can also be easily used for finding specific words after the fwd slash

Answer (score 2):

Using `PCRE` you could go for

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|/)[^e\n]*\Ke
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/6OzxcS/1/).

Comment: ++ For use of `\G` and keeping OP's original approach

Comment: i ended up using this in a different expression to match method parameters <3
this is it if you're curious `(?:\G|method\(|function\().*?\K(?:(["'])(?:(?<!\\)\\(?:\\\\)*\1|(?!\1).)*?\1|[^,\s=("']+)\s*(?=[,\)])`